# ActiveRecord model subclasses don't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is the trivial inheritance (STI) setup:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
end 

class Daughter < Parent
end

class Son < Parent
end
```

Quick try in console. Expecting `Parent.subclasses` to return two subclasses, but got nothing!

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Parent.subclasses
 => []
```

Also, calling

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Daughter.subclasses
 => []
```

,which correctly returns no children, makes Parent start recognizing Daughter as subclass:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Parent.subclasses
 => [Daughter(id: integer, type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)]
```

The same works for another subclass:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Son.subclasses
 => [] 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Parent.subclasses
 => [Daughter(id: integer, type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), Son(id: integer, type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)]
```

This is rails 3, but the same behavior exhibits on 2.3.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2389)

One workaround is to register the subclasses at the bottom of the base class file.

```
%w(daughter son).each {|r| require_dependency r } if Rails.env.development?
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a autoloading issue. The class are load only when you really need. You can try by example with the cache_classes = true configuration and see if this result is allways the same. I suppose is not.